# How to obtain counters for swap-in/swap-out on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, performance, swap, proc

I'm trying to obtain counters for swap-in/swap-out activity on CentOS 6.  The intention is to feed raw data into RRDtool to generate graphs, and use it to generate alerts.  I've had a look at common tools (`vmstat`, `smem`, and `dstat`), but these all seem aimed at interactive use, ie "from this point on" rather than providing raw access to counters.

`sar` is running on the system, and can generate historical reports, but doesn't seem like it tracks counters of swap-in/swap-out activity.

The [/proc manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) seems to indicate raw counters are available via `/proc/stat`:

```
page 5741 1808
    The number of pages the system paged in and the number
    that were paged out (from disk).
```

But that line is not present in the contents of `/proc/stat` on this system (kernel 2.6.32).  I'd prefer raw counters to avoid running/looping background processes like `vmstat`.  Looking at the contents of free isn't ideal, as it only shows percent used at a single point in time, not total activity since the last reading.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear if you search for page in/out caused by paging or by swapping. The difference is explained at several places here (https://superuser.com/questions/785447). The number of pages swapped and paged from `/proc/vmstat`.

Pages paged in / out

```
$ cat /proc/vmstat|grep pgpg
pgpgin 6920262
pgpgout 345654122
```

Pages swapped in / out

```
$ cat /proc/vmstat|grep pswp
pswpin 0
pswpout 0
```