# How would one monitor Swap usage?

Tags: monitoring, swap

I want to know if the Swap is used at all. `free` shows the usage of the memory:

```
# free
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1362084      169864       38288         724     1153932     1163816
Swap:       1048572           0     1048572
```

My understanding is that this is just a snapshot of the memory usage. The numbers change if I repeat the `free` command.

Is there a possibility to see if the Swap was even used?

Comment: For that you will probably have to use a monitoring daemon such as `monit` or `nagios`; this can also be done with log forwarders such as Splunk which can be trained to monitor system metrics such as RAM/Swap usage.

Comment: In my experience, it's very rare for swap to be completely freed once it has been used used. If it shows zero, then it most likely has not been used at all. However, in the example above, the system has no swap configured (total=0), so it will never use swap, because there is no swap to use.

Comment: Sorry, I was playing around. I'll correct the question.

Comment: If you are looking for a graphical tool for your desktop, or a server monitoring daemon with desktop client, you may like `gkrellm`

[http://gkrellm.srcbox.net/][1]

Very long list of features, including temperature, fan speeds, disk i/o, ram and swap use, network use, date/time, mail checker, all sorts of stuff.


  [1]: http://gkrellm.srcbox.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see swap activity even if the space was released between checks, you can use a counter for exactly that.

```
$ cat /proc/vmstat | grep pswp
pswpin 0
pswpout 0
```

This has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284315/how-to-obtain-counters-for-swap-in-swap-out-on-linux).

Comment: Yes, this shows the number of swapins and swapouts and I can see, if the swap was used at all.

Answer (score 2):

As you surmised, `free` simply gives you the system state at the moment the command is executed.  There are tools which can monitor this for you and perform actions based on a criterium or set of criteria which you select or describe.  For example, I use [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) in the course of my employ to observe system metrics, which makes it easy to see the swap usage of any system or systems over time: [image: Swap Monitoring Example]

The upshot, though, is that you will, if you want something to alert you if your system starts using swap space, to settle on one tool or another.  This something could be as simple as a `cron` job that watches the contents of `/proc/meminfo`.

Comment: I thought that 'free' displays '/proc/meminfo'. Nevertheless, the cronjob with Splunk should work.